# Image won't show up on HTML page

Tags: html, image, path

I am a disabled and complete HTML newbie who's trying to learn, but my brain damaged head needs some help please. I believe I read a post about the same issue but didn't understand it. I cannot get an image to load in my HTML file. The image is on my desktop but I don't know how to reference that path. Thank you for anyone's help.

Here's what I tried:

```
<img src="C:/images/brown-bear.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include a code snippet demonstrating how you're currently trying to reference an image in HTML.

Comment: Hi Sean and thank you , I did add the HTML code I tried that didn't work hopefully I did the edit right

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you copy the image to the same folder as the HTML file you are working with
Then `<img src="name of the image.extention" /> Something like this <Img src="picture.jpg" />`

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying my file is saved to my desktop and photos on my desktop in an images folder this is what I just tried and didn't work    img src=C:/images/brown-bear-1.jpg"brown-bear-1.jpg"/>